# Failing to deserialize geometry point data in Spring Boot REST API

Tags: postgis, point, geometry, java, api

I am working on a location-based REST API and so far everything is working fine, except for one controller which gives this error. I am new to this.

> 2022-03-16 16:28:37.842  WARN 7720 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] .c.j.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter : Failed to evaluate Jackson deserialization for type [[simple type, class com.example.Producttracking.dto.MetadataDto]]: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Conflicting setter definitions for property "x": org.postgis.Point#setX(double) vs org.postgis.Point#setX(int)

> 2022-03-16 16:28:37.847  WARN 7720 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] .c.j.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter : Failed to evaluate Jackson deserialization for type [[simple type, class com.example.Producttracking.dto.MetadataDto]]: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Conflicting setter definitions for property "x": org.postgis.Point#setX(double) vs org.postgis.Point#setX(int)

Here is the metadata entity:

```
package com.example.Producttracking.entity;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonDeserialize;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonSerialize;
import org.n52.jackson.datatype.jts.GeometryDeserializer;
import org.n52.jackson.datatype.jts.GeometrySerializer;
import org.postgis.Point;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalTime;


@Entity
@Table
public class Metadata implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long meta_id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "emp_id", referencedColumnName = "emp_id")
    private Employee employee;
    private LocalDate date;
    private LocalTime time;

    @JsonSerialize(using = GeometrySerializer.class)
    @JsonDeserialize(contentUsing = GeometryDeserializer.class)
    private Point location;

    public Metadata() {
    }

    public Metadata(Long meta_id, Employee employee, LocalDate date, LocalTime time, Point location) {
        this.meta_id = meta_id;
        this.employee = employee;
        this.date = date;
        this.time = time;
        this.location = location;
    }

    public Metadata(Employee employee, LocalDate date, LocalTime time, Point location) {
        this.employee = employee;
        this.date = date;
        this.time = time;
        this.location = location;
    }

    public Long getMeta_id() {
        return meta_id;
    }

    public void setMeta_id(Long meta_id) {
        this.meta_id = meta_id;
    }

    public Employee getEmployee() {
        return employee;
    }

    public void setEmployee(Employee employee) {
        this.employee = employee;
    }

    public LocalDate getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(LocalDate date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public LocalTime getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public void setTime(LocalTime time) {
        this.time = time;
    }

    public Point getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public void setLocation(Point location) {
        this.location = location;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Metadata{" +
                "meta_id=" + meta_id +
                ", employee=" + employee +
                ", date=" + date +
                ", time=" + time +
                ", location=" + location +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Here is the the DTO:

```
package com.example.Producttracking.dto;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonDeserialize;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonSerialize;
import lombok.Data;
import org.n52.jackson.datatype.jts.GeometryDeserializer;
import org.n52.jackson.datatype.jts.GeometrySerializer;
import org.postgis.Point;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalTime;

@Data
public class MetadataDto {
    private Long emp_id;
    private LocalDate date;
    private LocalTime time;

    @JsonSerialize(using = GeometrySerializer.class)
    @JsonDeserialize(contentUsing = GeometryDeserializer.class)
    private Point location;
}
```

Here is the controller:

```
package com.example.Producttracking.controller;

import com.example.Producttracking.dto.MetadataDto;
import com.example.Producttracking.entity.Metadata;
import com.example.Producttracking.services.MetadataService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "api/v1/metadata")
public class MetadataController {

    private final MetadataService metadataService;

    @Autowired
    public MetadataController(MetadataService metadataService) {
        this.metadataService = metadataService;
    }
    
    @GetMapping
    public List<Metadata> getMetadata(){

        return metadataService.getMetadata();
    }

    @PostMapping
    public void registerMetadata (@RequestBody MetadataDto metadataDto){

        metadataService.registerMetadata(metadataDto);
    }
}
```

and here is the service:

```
package com.example.Producttracking.services;

import com.example.Producttracking.dto.MetadataDto;
import com.example.Producttracking.entity.Metadata;
import com.example.Producttracking.repository.MetadataRepository;
import org.modelmapper.ModelMapper;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

@Service
public class MetadataService {

    private final MetadataRepository metadataRepository;
    private final ModelMapper modelMapper;

    @Autowired
    public MetadataService(MetadataRepository metadataRepository, ModelMapper modelMapper) {
        this.metadataRepository = metadataRepository;
        this.modelMapper = modelMapper;
    }

    public List<Metadata> getMetadata() {
        return metadataRepository.findAll();
    }

    public void registerMetadata(MetadataDto metadataDto) {

        Metadata metadata = modelMapper.map(metadataDto,Metadata.class);

        Optional<Metadata> metadataOptional = metadataRepository.findById(metadata.getMeta_id());

        if (metadataOptional.isPresent()){
            throw new IllegalStateException("metadata exist");
        }

        metadataRepository.save(metadata);
    }


}
```